# Getting started with OpenCV on Macbook

Tags: macos, opencv

I installed openCV on snow leopard with homebrew. Any opencv program I try to run cannot find the required header files.

I understand that the paths of the header files has to be defined. I need help with how I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **pkg-config** to make your job easier:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```